# How to do write a mysql statement which list elements which start with a letter of a list of characters? regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to write a mysql statement to list the elements which have name which starts with t or s.

I used these 2 but they don't work:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '[s|t]%';
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '[st]%';
```

I used these separately and it works:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE 's%';
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE 't%';
```

I found a tutorial with examples for SQL. Not mySQL. Are there differences in regex?Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql uses REGEXP so it would actually look like this:

```
 select * from customers where name REGEXP '^[st]';
```

Comment: I tried it but it lists elements which don't start just with s or t.

Comment: I think it is: select * from customers where name REGEXP '^[s|t]';

Comment: Wrong!  That includes `|`.  Either `'^[st]'` or `'^(s|t)'`.  The former uses a "set of characters"; the latter refers to "this or that" and can handle things longer than a single letter.